# SQL Server function always returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm pulling my hair out here.  The function below always returns null, even though it works fine if I pull the code out into a query window and set the input parameters manually.  The idea is that I have a different query based on the month, because each month's average value is stored in a different column.  I know, the table's not well normalized, but it's what I have to work with.  What am I missing?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_currentShareBal]
(
@currentDate    datetime,
@account        integer,
@acctType       varchar
)  
RETURNS money AS  
BEGIN

DECLARE @dte char(10)
DECLARE @returnVal money
DECLARE @month int

SET @dte = CONVERT(char(10), @currentDate, 101)
SET @month = MONTH(@currentDate)

-- because of the table strucure the actual query depends on the month
IF @month = 1 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg1)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 2 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg2)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 3 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg3)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 4 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg4)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 5 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg5)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 6 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg6)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 7 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg7)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 8 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg8)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 9 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg9)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 10 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg10)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 11 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg11)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

IF @month = 12 SET @returnVal = (SELECT SUM(avg12)
                        FROM COSHAVG
                        WHERE cuID = @account
                        AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
                        AND acctType = @acctType)

RETURN @returnVal

END
GO
```

Comment: Is `COSHAVG` part of in the `dbo` scheme?

Comment: What is avgBalanceMonth? Is comparing it to a 10 character date intentional?

Comment: How are you calling this function? You might consider setting default values for your input parameters and see if that changes the behavior... if you then perhaps your calling code is misbehaving... For example: in .NET the built-in solution may convert `NULL` strings to blank... just a thought

Comment: You know that by not specifying a length for @acctType varchar you get one character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your function definition. It's hard to tell as you haven't posted your table's definition.

Does this work? If not, can you post  a scripted Create on the COSHAVG table?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_currentShareBal]
(
    @currentDate    datetime,
    @account        integer,
    @acctType       varchar(50)
)  
RETURNS money
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dte varchar(20)
    DECLARE @returnVal money
    DECLARE @month int

    SET @dte = CONVERT(varchar, @currentDate, 101)
    SET @month = MONTH(@currentDate)

    SELECT
        @returnVal=SUM(CASE
            WHEN @month = 1 THEN avg1
            WHEN @month = 2 THEN avg2
            WHEN @month = 3 THEN avg3
            WHEN @month = 4 THEN avg4
            WHEN @month = 5 THEN avg5
            WHEN @month = 6 THEN avg6
            WHEN @month = 7 THEN avg7
            WHEN @month = 8 THEN avg8
            WHEN @month = 9 THEN avg9
            WHEN @month = 10 THEN avg10
            WHEN @month = 11 THEN avg11
            WHEN @month = 12 THEN avg12
        END)
    FROM COSHAVG
    WHERE cuID = @account
    AND avgBalanceMonth =  @dte
    AND acctType = @acctType

    RETURN @returnVal
END
GO
```

Comment: This works, as does Stuart's almost identical code below.  I wasn't aware I could use a case statement like that to determine the column, and it is much cleaner.  Apparently Elroy in his comment above hit it on the head.  When I add the a length to the varchar value in my original code it works too.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out things to look for in the comments, but here's a cleaner way to rewrite the function (no real change in behavior, just easier to maintain):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_currentShareBal]
    (
      @currentDate DATETIME
    , @account INTEGER
    , @acctType VARCHAR (100) 
    )
RETURNS MONEY
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dte CHAR(10)
        DECLARE @returnVal MONEY
        DECLARE @month INT
        SET @dte = CONVERT(CHAR(10), @currentDate, 101)
        SET @month = MONTH(@currentDate) 
         -- because of the table strucure the actual query depends on the month 

        SELECT  @returnVal = SUM(CASE WHEN @month = 1 THEN avg1
                                      WHEN @month = 2 THEN avg2
                                    /*...*/
                                      WHEN @month = 12 THEN avg12
                                 END)
        FROM    COSHAVG
        WHERE   cuID = @account
                AND avgBalanceMonth = @dte
                AND acctType = @acctType


        RETURN @returnVal
    END
```

Comment: Thanks, Stuart.  Looks like SpectralGhost posted nearly identical code about 3 minutes before you.  Wish I could mark both as the answer.